# how to order monthly in ggplot2 without alphabetiacally

Tags: r, ggplot2

hi I'm a beginner of `RStudio`.

I want to order monthly but it automatically changed to alphabetically

Here is my code:

```
A <- ggplot(data=BTNFDI,aes(x=month,y=INDFDI.net.))
A+geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+geom_text(aes(label = INDFDI.net.), vjust = -0.2)
```

But I got this:

[image]

Comment: If the variable is a character ggplot will use alphabetical order, you need to define your x variable as Date or factor to avoid that.

Comment: If the column in your dataframe is not a date but you want it to be ordered, you can define as a factor and set the levels via: `df$column <- factor(df$column, levels=c(vector of levels in your preferred order))`